# failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart connection refused 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upstart

I am trying to install plexmediaplayer on to my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I have recently started from scratch, with my server by installing 14.04lts then upgrading to 16.04. Before I upgraded, and before I started from scratch, I was able to install plex to my box but now I get the 'failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart connection refused' error